# Reference sf::RenderWindow from another source file in SFML

Tags: c++, game-loop, sfml

In SFML, How would you be able to reference a window in your `main.cpp` file to another source file? I want to be able to reference the window made in `main.cpp` from `player.cpp`, so I can keep everything organized and not have so much stuff in `main.cpp`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Main.cpp

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::VideoMode vmode(800, 600, 32);
    window.create(vmode, "Test");

    PlayerTest(2);

    //Game Loop
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // REMEMBER TO FIX PLAYER.CPP

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void PlayerTest(float speed);

#endif
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"

void PlayerTest(float speed) {

    sf::RectangleShape square(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
    square.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);

    //window from Main.cpp I need to reference
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) {
            square.move(0, -speed);
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) {
            square.move(0, speed);
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
            square.move(-speed, 0);
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
            square.move(speed, 0);
        }

        //Window from Main.cpp I need to reference
        window.clear();
        window.draw(square);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read a basic C++ tutorial. Why not simply pass the window instace as a reference or a pointer to the `PlayerTest` function? Anyways I don't feel like this is gamedev specific. Your generic game flow looks also quite wrong, as you have two while loops after each other.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Thanks for the help, I'm kind of new to C++ and I'll read up again on some tutorials I have.

Answer (score 0):

Have your main.cpp call an object `Game`. This Game object contains everything else. Your game first initializes the Window, then passes the reference to Player when it initializes it.